# Magento 1.9 - CMS Home Page not show content

Tags: magento-1.9, cms, backend, home

I have a problem with a cms homepage in my store. So, in my store `i deleted the menu item from home page` and I kept only the menu items of the individual product categories.   But for first page of my store, in System, i selected "Home Page Custom" for default page.

I have already selected the CMS page viewable in Italian and English language of the store. But still, when I go to my store at www.site.com/store i see the template of my site with menu and footer but without the content of my CMS Page. Only when i selected language of my store in Italian or English i see the content of my CMS home page.

How can I view the default content of my CMS Page without having to select the language?

Thank you very much

[image]

Comment: Have u checked by setting the home page for default store view.

Comment: Yes man, i checked the home page but i can see the content only when i select a language of my store...

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: Are you use the CMS page you selected is visible on all store views, and is set to `Enabled`? Run a reindex and flush cache after.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the problem. In my .htaccess file I had the following entry.

```
SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE 1
```

By commenting this out the front pages returned.

I hope this helps someone in the future.

And also check for the static blocks on the home page then check the stores and set it as the CMS home page.

Comment: I haven't this entry in my .htaccess. I've already selected my cms page as the default page in System -> Web but without success...What else could I do?

Comment: Can you send one screenshot of the System -> Web -> Default Pages

Comment: Adding image. It is possible that the cause is to have deleted the home menu item? Thanks.

Comment: Asfar i know ,htaccess have no `SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE 1` we use this to debug or same form index.php (ver 1.x)